# What is the 'units' digit of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $n$ be the smallest integer:$7n$ has $1984$ digits

What is the units digit of $n$?

My attempt:

I have deduced that the number $7n$ must begin with a $1$ and have $1982$ $0s$ after that, ending in the digit $c$ which I need to find.

Next I used long division to determine that:

$\frac{7n}{7} = \frac{10000000...00c}{7} =$ the $6$ digits $142857$ repeated many times till the number terminates on $c$ = one of the digits $1,4,2,8,5,7$

So to determine $c$, We calculate $1984mod6 \equiv 4mod6$

Therefore $c =$ the fourth digit in the pattern of 6 repeated digits = $8$

Is my attempt correct, and if yes, is it efficient?

EDIT:

Having looked at the inputs from members on the site, I have identified my errors. I should have used $1983\equiv 3mod6$ and then used the remainders corresponding to each recurring digit i.e. $1 \rightarrow 1, 4 \rightarrow 1, 2\rightarrow 3, 8 \rightarrow 2, 5\rightarrow 6, 7 \rightarrow 4$ Then the remainder corresponding to the third digit in $142857$ gives us $c=3$

Comment: well, if $10^{1083}\equiv 6 \pmod 7$ then $10^{1083}+1\equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at

Comment: "What is the units digit of $n$?" Did you mean $7n$?

Comment: So we know that $10^{1083}+1$ is an integer with $1084$ digits AND it is divisible by $7$.  Clearly it is the smallest such, yes?

Comment: @mathlove I did mean $n$

Comment: @lulu But the number needs to be 1984 digits long

Comment: It is $1984$ digits long.  Remember, $10^1$ is two digits long...$10^2$ is three digits long...$10^{1083}$ is $1084$ digits long.  Adding $1$ doesn't change the length.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but could you make your comment into a more idiot proof one since I still don't understand what you're trying to say in relation to the question

Comment: @mrnovice: OK. I think that lulu has typos. He should mean that $10^{1\color{red}{9}83}\equiv 6\pmod 7$. So, $7n=100\cdots 01$. Now consider multiplication instead of division. Hint : $7\times 3=21$.

Comment: @mathlove  I don't think there are any typos in what I wrote.  True, I didn't do the division by $7$, but neither did I claim to.

Comment: @lulu: So, you actually meant $10^{1\color{red}{0}83}\equiv 6\pmod 7$ instead of $10^{1\color{red}{9}83}\equiv 6\pmod 7$?

Comment: @mathlove  Thanks!  For some reason, I am systematically mixing $1084$ and $1984$.  One of those days.  I'll post something below which (hopefully) omits the blunders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  in the comments I, for whatever reason, systematically confused $1984$ with $1084$ (and $1983$ with $1083$.  In a weird way, I was consistent there).  Let me post something which, hopefully, avoids the blunders.

First, let's produce the smallest multiple of $7$ which has $1984$ digits, call it $M$. Since every seventh integer is divisible by $7$ we know there is one near $10^{1983}$.

First:  note that $10^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$ and $1983\equiv 3 \pmod 6$.  It follows that $$10^{1983}\equiv 10^3\equiv 6 \pmod 7$$

This in turn implies that $$10^{1983}+1\equiv 0 \pmod 7$$  We see we have found our $M$.

Now, to answer the question, we need to compute the units place of $\frac M7$.  But  $7a\equiv 1\pmod {10} \implies a\equiv 3\pmod {10}$ so the units place we seek is $\fbox 3$.

Comment: Ok I think I understand my mistake now, I should have used $1983\equiv 3mod6$ and then used the remainders corresponding to each recurring digit i.e. $1 \rightarrow 1, 4 \rightarrow 1, 2\rightarrow 3, 8 \rightarrow 2, 5\rightarrow 6, 7 \rightarrow 4$ Then the remainder corresponding to the third digit in $142857$ gives us $c=3$ as you arrived at

Comment: That sounds right.  Of course, you don't really need to compute the other digits (though you certainly can).  If all you want is the result $\pmod {10}$ then you can just work $\pmod {10}$.  We have $M\equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ so we want $n$ such that $7n\equiv M\equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ and that immediately gets us $n\equiv 3 \pmod {10}$.

Comment: Yes I see this method is more efficient. Was making sure I understood where I went wrong in my initial method.